# Typo3 8 LTS: CKEditor Dropdown Width

Tags: ckeditor, typo3-8.x

I love the new CKEditor in Typo3, much better than the old RTE.

But I have an question about its configuration:
Is it possible to increase the width of the dropdowns? 
I've tried the tips:

```
.cke_combo_text { width:auto !important; }
.cke_combopanel { height:600px !important; }
```

But it doesn't work. Any tips?

[image: Inrease the dropdown width]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!
We are using our own template-distribution.

You have to add in the **ext_tables.php**

> //Overwrite BE-Stylings if needed. e.g. increase the select-width of ckeditor for Inline- / Block-Styles
>
> **if( TYPO3_MODE == "BE"){
>       $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['backend']['stylesheetDirectories']['[your_ext_key]'] = 'EXT:[your_ext_key]/Resources/Private/Backend/';**
>   }

Then you can add a stylesheet:

eg. **typo3conf/ext/[your_ext_key]/Resources/Private/Backend/rte_ckeditor.scss**

```
.cke_combopanel {
    min-width: 35rem !important;

    .cke_panel_frame {
        min-width: 35rem !important;
    }
}
```